Has Macron's new government indicated whether it is "leaning" hard left or hard right?
From BBC Sept 5 - Barnier becomes new French PM and bids to end turmoil 

Veteran French conservative Michel Barnier has taken over as prime minister, almost two months after France's snap elections ended in political stalemate.
He said France had come to a "serious moment" and he was facing it with humility: "All political forces will have to be respected and listened to, and I mean all."
President Emmanuel Macron named the EU's former chief Brexit negotiator, ending weeks of talks with political parties and potential candidates.

Now, the new government, despite an alliance with the right-center Republicans, does not have a majority in parliament and could be taken down if the NFP left (of which Melenchon's hard-left LFI is a big part) and the LePen's hard-right voted against it.
Presumably, the government will try to avoid giving those two a reason to band together, but has there been any indication which side the new government will be more conciliatory towards?
LePen seems happier

Marine Le Pen has made clear her party will not take part in his administration, but she said he at least appeared to meet National Rally's initial requirement, as someone who "respected different political forces".

Than Melenchon's take on things:

"This is now essentially a Macron-Le Pen government," said Mr Mélenchon, referring to the leader of the far-right National Rally (RN).

But is this based on something else than Barnier being center-right?  There wasn't anyone else left, besides Macron entering an alliance with the RN or the left grouping dominated by LFI.
(a somewhat similar conundrum to what is happening in some German states)
Has the new government indicated concessions to either side?  Changes in policy? Or is it just hoping to stay out of trouble by avoiding giving both a reason to unite for a no-confidence vote?
Party Group : Seats

New Popular Front : 193 (not a unified block, see comments and many of which are moderate)
Ensemble alliance : 166 (Macron) +
Republicans + Right: 47 (Barnier) +
National Rally + allies: 142
Others: 29


There's some debate about my characterization of the NFP as Hard-left.  I would be the first to criticize that, if the NFP was mostly composed of past, center-left like the Parti Socialiste or the Greens.
They are not.  Most of them are from Melenchon's LFI, with a sizable additions from the French Communists. The French Communists were not a huge deal as as small group within say Mitterand's government.  They are a bigger deal when are in an alliance with LFI and outweigh the moderate constituents of the NFP.  And, why, exactly, do I claim Melenchon and the LFI are hard left?  Well, because the man has a long history of admiring Chavez and ambiguous(?) towards Frexit.  Presenting him as somehow not hard left really is quite, quite, misleading.
Again, I have no problem with the rump Socialists or Greens in the NFP.  But they certainly have allied themselves with groups that some (and that includes me) consider to be hard left.

The problem of this question is that "hard" left/right has no definition in the French political spectrum and it ends up being used as a disqualifying strawman. There is a definition for extrême, or in English "far", left/right. For the left, in short, it's communist revolutionary parties. Neither LFI nor the PCF are such parties. They're not far-left. They're just left. Calling them, or the NFP, far-left would be a lie with no basis in reality.


But is this based on something else than Barnier being center-right? There wasn't anyone else left, besides Macron entering an alliance with the RN or the left grouping dominated by LFI.

For starters, Barnier is not center-right. He campaigned on the right of the mainstream right-wing party for its internal “primary” last year, e.g. called for a “total freeze on immigration” including family reunion. It would be a very odd choice if the hope was to get some support from the left or maybe try to split the left-wing coalition.
Most importantly, Macron was constantly in touch with Le Pen during the search and ruled out several right or center-right figures based on her preferences. At the same time, he and his surrogates spent a lot of time in the last few months painting LFI as far-left and beyond the pale. He also ruled out the center-left candidate put forward by the left-wing coalition (Lucie Castets) almost immediately so there isn't much ambiguity on the type of coalition he is trying to build.
In fact, Mélenchon is not the only prominent politician who complained about Macron relying on the far right for support, François Hollande, who is as centrist as it gets and apparently nurtures his own presidential ambitions, leveled the same accusation last week-end. We will see who makes it to the cabinet and whether the government tries one of Macron's trademark “en même temps” move by pushing for some seemingly left-wing policy but until now everything points to a government that strongly “leans RN”.

Well, that certainly weighs more in on the "leans RN" side of things, does it not?  Which is what the Q was asking about.

@ItalianPhilosopher Yes, indeed.

To some extent (meaning immigration) he appears to lean RN:

The prime minister has so far given them a clear nod by putting the topic of immigration – the RN’s main issue – on top of his priority list.
In a TV interview last week, he compared French borders to “sieves”, warning that “migratory flows are not under control.” A few days later, on the sidelines of a meeting with his own Les Républicains (LR) political family, he vowed to “control” immigration “with “rigour and tenacity”. [...]
Among other ‘immediate’ priorities of the time, he had called to “drastically reduce” family reunification, “facilitate deportations”, put an end to free medical aid for undocumented migrants, and reform asylum laws.
“It’s undeniable that Michel Barnier seems to have the same position as we do on migration,” far-right RN parliamentary group President Marine Le Pen told weekly La Tribune Dimanche last week.

RN has made more concrete demands, some public and some probably not. E.g., they demand new ministers in key roles, like the interior ministry.

On Monday, the RN president, Jordan Bardella, who has said “nothing can be done without the RN”, warned the new premier not to continue with a Macronist programme. He threatened a censure motion against any new government that “recycled” Macron’s interior minister, Gérald Darmanin, or justice minister, Éric Dupond-Moretti – both on the centre-right of the previous government.
“If Michel Barnier continues with the programme driven by Emmanuel Macron since seven years, which was severely defeated in the European and legislative election ballot boxes … then the government will fall,” he told RTL radio. “If Mr Barnier echoes the hopes expressed by millions of French people, then we’ll vote for the bills on a case-by-case basis.

Whether they demand specific persons, IDK right now. Even with these concession RN might not be happy for more than the strictly required constitutional term of 12 months.

At the weekend, Le Pen told RN leaders she hoped Barnier’s tenure as head of the government would be “as short as possible”. “We find ourselves in a situation where the party that got the least votes is in charge of forming a government. It cannot hold,” she said.
[...] Macron cannot dissolve parliament and call another general election until 12 months after the last dissolution.

The left's main demand seem to be to revert the pension law that increased the retirement age. So far I've not seen any indication Barnier plans to entertain that.
Anyhow 2/3 of the French seem unhappy with him as PM already.

A poll by Ipsos published at the weekend suggested 64% of French people believed Macron had ignored the result of the election. Among those who voted for the NFP, that figure rose to 91%. Only one-third of those polled approved of his choice of Barnier as PM.

(From the same poll, Macron's overall popularity seems to also hover around 30% right now.)
Pre-election, on the economy, both the RN and the left NPF (contra Macron) made plans/promises to significantly increase spending, although perhaps not with the same priorities. It remains to be seen if any of these [differences] will scupper's Barniers government, or if RN will be content with the immigration bone they got.



While the RN also demanded the pension reform be rolled back, they seem to want that done in a 'progressive' manner, which probably means it won't be an immediate/hard demand like from the NPF.

Mr Bardella promises to strike down Mr Macron’s pension reform, which raised the legal minimum retirement age from 62 years to 64; but now says that this would be “progressive”.

And on this he seems to have gotten some vague agreement from Barnier:

As a gesture of conciliation, Barnier announced his intention to reopen the debate on pension reform, which the left and far-right are planning to dismantle.
However, he made it clear that the new government is not going to call everything into question and the existing law will remain in place.
On the other hand, Barnier confirmed his intention to open the debate on "improving" the reform.

RN's own post-election position on the budget isn't terribly clear, but they also have unenviable choices of their own:

if Le Pen brings down the new government, she risks being accused of plunging the country into chaos. If she supports the passage of an “austerity” budget — even passively — she’ll be accused of becoming another mainstream politician propping up the status quo by those on the left, as well as dissident voices on the far right.

Barnier himself seems to have not revealed (thus far) whether he plans to entertain RN's demand to raise the minimum wage (be it by cutting the social contributions in that tax bracket) or reduce France's EU contributions. He just spoke in very general terms of "fiscal fairness" and "justice in taxation", which is anybody's guess what it means.
Some other potential demands from the RN that I'm not sure Barnier has commented on are electoral reform (in favor of RN, of course):

Mr Barnier will get no help from the left. The four-party left-wing alliance, dominated by Jean-Luc Mélenchon’s hard-left Unsubmissive France, is fuming. It holds the biggest parliamentary bloc, with 193 seats, and claims that Mr Macron has “stolen” the election. The alliance will vote against Mr Barnier at the first chance.
That means that, awkwardly, the survival of Mr Barnier’s future government is now largely in the hands of none other than Marine Le Pen. Her hard-right friends form the third-biggest parliamentary bloc, with 142 seats, and her promise not to vote immediately against Mr Barnier helped him to clinch the job. Now she, in effect, has her finger on the ejector-seat button. Among her demands is the introduction of proportional representation for the legislative vote, which would benefit her own party.

Thus far only the left wing came out in public rallies against the Barnier government. The yellow vests appear to have stayed out of that for now.

what does the chart from the economist has to do with anything?

@njzk2: budget demands. The chart was based on electoral promises to spend on this or that or cut this or that tax, during the campaign, AFAIU. It indeed might not have any relevance if the parties have completely forgotten about all those promises, but that doesn't seem to be entirely the case.

It's a biased chart, though. Several economists have shown how the program of the NFP would be financed without increasing the deficit. (If any projection means anything anyway, considering what Le Maire has been doing in the last few years)

Barnier is from LR, former UMP, which itself comes from RPR the first party he joined when he was 27.
He is expected to do a classical conservative politics, taking a conservative stance on societal and social issues (he voted against decriminalization
of homosexuality back in the days, he is strongly advocating for stronger immigration policies), and very liberal on the economics aspects (privatisation, reducing states spendings).
The slights detail is that he needs far-right votes to get his policies passed into parliament. The left said it will systematically oppose him. So his policies to respect a far-right alignment, meaning he should go even further right on societal/social issues (especially immigration), but should add a little of protectionism to his economic policies (with the difference that they should be made with a “préférence national” bias, it should only target what is appreciated as “truly french”).
So it’s a bit complicated to know exactly what his politics will be like. The only things he aligns with his allies of the far right is having a tougher policy on societal issues, so that’s might be what he focus on to not be censored and be dismissed.

"reducing states spendings" this is not necessarily true: Le Maire would have been expected to do that as well, and yet found a way to funnel a lot of state spending into the pockets of the wealthy classes.

In addition to the statement you quoted, Barnier declared he not only intended to listen to the left but also wanted people from the left in his government.
That makes him the subject of pressure from all parts: the hard left trying to prevent him from driving a wedge through the left coalition, Macron's camp trying to push as many ministers as possible into his government, his (ex?) Republicain friends rushing in for the opportunity as well, and Le Pen pushing her far-right agenda with the threat of a no-confidence vote if Barnier doesn't comply.
Something he surely learned during his long political career is to yield as little information as possible to his opponents until his final decision is made, to prevent anything that could undermine him in a difficult period. He's currently trying to keep the negociations airtight. Besides, he's trying to appear as an "anti-Macron" in terms of public relations and play it fair, i.e. no "feelers" leaked to the press, no gaslighting his political partners, no sudden coat-turning. So no, he has not indicated anything yet as we speak.
